# How to get id of a button from a group of buttons on click event using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to get the Id of a button for DOM manipulation. I have a group of buttons and I want to get Id of only the button which is clicked. 
My Code is:-

```
  <div class="row mb-5" id="widthRow">
  <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
  <p class="text-info font-weight-bold">Width :-</p>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="200">200px</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="400">400px</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="600">600px</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="800">800px</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I tried searching on stack overflow and got an answer with code:-

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
            alert(this.id);
        };
    }
    });
```

But when I use it on my page, I get the error:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ikyB.jpg.

Note:- (I also used this code with getElementsByClassName. )

I tried searching for this error also. And some said that DOM is not loaded before manipulation. So, I added defer to script and also added 
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {}

But nothing helped. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll try and point you in the right direction.. You should read about closures..

Comment: Also read about `addEventListener`

Comment: @AnkurMittal Thank You for pointing. I am learning ES6 and have read about closures. But the problem was solved by the answer below. BTW thank you and I will try to apply ES6 in my future code after I learn it fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are executing your code before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place the code at the bottom of the body or wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event):

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for *stylesheets*, *images*, and *subframes* to finish loading.

***Please Note:*** As `getElementsByTagName()` returns *HTMLCollection* which maintains 0 based indexing, you are iterating your loop more than the length of buttons, change `<=` to `<`.

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < buttonsCount; i++) {
      buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
        alert(this.id);
      };
    }
  });
</script>


<div class="row mb-5" id="widthRow">
  <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
  <p class="text-info font-weight-bold">Width :-</p>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="200">200px</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="400">400px</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="600">600px</button>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w" id="800">800px</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks. It solved my problem. Bad on my side that I didn't spot that error.